# Where can I get version 16.0.0 of libfreetype.6.dylib for ImageMagick on MAMP

Tags: imagemagick, mamp

When running imagemagick under MAMP I get the error message:

```
command output :"dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
Referenced from: /Applications/MAMP/bin/ImageMagick/ImageMagick-6.7.9/bin/convert
Reason: Incompatible library version: convert requires version 16.0.0 or later, but libfreetype.6.dylib provides version 15.0.0"
```

I have searched everywhere I can think of but can't find a solution to this. One posting I saw suggested commenting out the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH in envvars but this did not make any difference.

Comment: Same error here.. how'd you solve it?

Comment: I'm having the same issue as you and JackFuchs. Were you able to come up with a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out. I ran:

```
$ locate libfreetype.6.dylib
```

and discovered that there are multiple version of that dylib including a version in /opt/local/lib where macports installs imagemagick. I copied that version to the location in MAMP where it was installed and it solved the issue.

```
$ cp /opt/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/
```

Make sure you make a backup of the MAMP version before copying over it just in case something goes wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. For me works this:

```
sudo port selfupdate
sudo port install ImageMagick

sudo pecl update-channels
sudo pecl install imagick
```

Then I run

```
find . -name "imagick.so"
```

and use the given path in MAMP php.ini.

In the end I commented out the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH lines in /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/envvars