# Incompatible library version: libtk8.6.dylib requires ... when installing R package

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to install the R package ggplot2, though the error that I am getting seems unrelated to that specific package. I am running on Mac OSX 10.6.8. The error message is at the bottom of this message. What happened was:

1. I opened up R and typed `install.packages("ggplot2")`. After typing this, an X11 window opened saying that I should update to the latest version of X11. I clicked through and updated X11. The install went through fine, ending with a big green check mark.
2. Then, I thought, "let me check if R is up to date as well, as the ggplot documentation suggests updating R before installing ggplot". So I opened up R, and clicked "check for updates". Lo and behold! an update appeared. I downloaded and installed the update. The install went through fine, ending with a big green check mark.
3. When I opened R, I typed `install.packages("ggplot2")` and I got the message below:

---

```
> install.packages("ggplot2");
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:
call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
error: unable to load shared object
'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so':
dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so, 10):
Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libtk8.6.dylib
Reason: Incompatible library version: libtk8.6.dylib requires version 14.0.0 or later, but libfreetype.6.dylib provides version 13.0.0
```

---

Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768368/where-can-i-get-version-16-0-0-of-libfreetype-6-dylib-for-imagemagick-on-mamp) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537011/imagemagick-issue-on-lion-installed-with-homebrew)

Comment: The direction presented in that post didn't solve my issue

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the [latest version of XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org). It worked for me.