# ggplot2 package failing to load

Tags: r, ggplot2, x11, rstudio

I just recently updated my Rstudio to the 0.98.1103 release and now I'm unable to load ggplot it keeps throwing the following error. Any ideas what is going on?

```
> library(ggplot2)

Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so, 10): Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libXft.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libtk8.6.dylib
  Reason: image not found
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2
```

I tried removing the tcltk library and ggplot2 and reinstalling them now I'm getting a different set of errors:

```
> library(ggplot2)
Error : package ‘tcltk’ does not have a namespace
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’

> library(tcltk)
Error in library(tcltk) : ‘tcltk’ is not a valid installed package
```

Comment: Isn't this the same problem as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432320/incompatible-library-version-libtk8-6-dylib-requires-when-installing-r-pack

Comment: The suggestions in that post didn't solve my issue

Comment: I also just got this message today after updating several packages.  (install.packages(c("boot", "BradleyTerry2", "car", "class", "cluster", "colorspace", "foreign", "haven", "Hmisc", "KernSmooth", "lattice", "manipulate", "MASS", "mgcv", "nlme", "nnet", "Rcpp", "rpart", "spatial", "survival"))) Prior to the install, I did not have any problems running ggplot.

Comment: I also update all my packages similar to what you have listed

Comment: I don't know if it is the R studio update.  I think it is the latest ggplot2 package on CRAN.  I just updated ggplot2 on my MacBook and have this exact same error.  I need to have this working tomorrow, I will be switching to an non-updated system or using my Windows system.

Comment: First, I'm running Mavericks and ggplot2 seems to be working fine. So it could be a couple of things: 1) I'm still running "Pumpkin Helmet". 2) RStudio Version 0.98.1062. 3) I have XQuartz installed (I've been noticing that X11 now opens up whenever I open RStudio). I'm pretty sure I have all of those packages installed (and updated) so I don't think that's the issue...

Comment: I think the issue is with the Rstudio update..... Where is @hadley when you need him.

Comment: I've got the same issue here. Wondering if the "Smooth Sidewalk" update is not so smooth...

Answer (score 1):

Seems like X11 is not installed on your system. Try installing `xorg` (if you're running Linux) or `XQuartz` if you're on OSX.

Comment: I have XQuartz installed on my computer ggplot has always work for me no problem but after updating Rstudio its not working anymore...

Comment: I had the same symptoms as the OP but I additionally upgraded to OS X Yosemite. Since then I was having this issue with ggplot. I thought I had XQuartz installed, but just in case I reinstalled XQuartz 2.7.7 and now ggplot2 is working for me.